# Coincident boundaries of sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

At the end of my lecture, which introduced closed sets and boundaries of sets, my professor asked the following question:

Let $S,T,V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $int(S) \not = \emptyset$, $int(T) \not = \emptyset$ and $int(V) \not = \emptyset$.

Question: Is it possible that the boundaries of $S,T$ and $V$ coincide?

The first thing that came to my mind was that you could let $S=T=V$ so they obviously would be coincident, but then she stated that she had forgotten to say that they cannot be equal.

With only 2 sets (i.e. $S,T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$) this problem would be easy, just let, for example, $S=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 \leq 0, x_2 \leq 0 \rbrace$ and $T=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0 \rbrace$ so that boundaries of the sets would be the line $x_2=0$.

Could anyone give me some hints how to tackle this problem? Please remember that I know almost nothing about topology, a quick Google search told me that this problem relates to topology. So any reading material on this topic would be nice, because it intrigues me.

Although it is not homework, it is tagged as such because I don't want full answers (for now) but try to solve the problem on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: after rereading my book I found the following theorem: The set of boundary points of a set $S$ equals $cl(S) \cap cl(S^c)$. $cl(X)$ denotes the closure of the set $X$.

Hence, my problem is as follows: Does there exist some $S,T,V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $cl(S) \cap cl(S^c)=cl(T) \cap cl(T^c)=cl(V) \cap cl(V^c)$.

Comment: If the sets can have the same interior, it's not difficult to come up with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question you want to ask is "is it possible to have three mutually disjoint sets whose boundaries are all equal?"

One way to describe the boundary of a set $S$ is that $P$ is on the boundary of $S$ if there's a sequence $s_1, s_2, \ldots$ of points in $S$ whose limit is $P$, or, if you prefer, with the property that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} dist(s_n, P) = 0$.

Based on this notion, a point $P$ can be on the boundary of $S, T,$ and $U$ only if there's a sequence of $S$-points approaching $P$, a sequence of $T$-points doing so, and a sequence of $U$-points doing so.

One way to make something like this happen is to try to CONSTRUCT it: Start with something like an island in a warm sea with two lakes, hot and cold, on the island. Many points of the island are NOT on the boundary of the sea or either lake. Can you alter the lakes and/or the sea (by digging canals) to make the island points be closer to both lakes and the sea?

This idea is worked out in some detail on about page 2 or 3 of Alexandroff's Introduction to Topology. For now, I'll just leave you with that starting point.

Comment: Could you give me an ISBN of that book? For some odd reason, I cannot find it on Google and my university library only has a book with that title written by Solomon Lefschetz.

Comment: And regarding the answer: I read your previous (deleted) post and I find it hard to imagine such construction by making canals. Any chance that you have a picture, or even better, a .gif? Thanks anyway!

Comment: My mistake -- it's "Elementary Concepts in Topology". A PDF is here: http://carlossicoli.free.fr/A/Alexandroff_P.-Elementary_concepts_in_Topology(1932)(62s).pdf 

See Figure 4 on page 4, and the accompanying explanation.

The key idea is that the "land mass" at each instant is a path-connected space (you can get from any place to any other without getting your feet wet) so the canal-diggers can always dig over towards any spot that's too far from their particular flavor of water.

Comment: One more thing: I was looking at Hocking and Young's topology book two nights ago and they described the same example, calling it "The Lakes of Wada". A google search on that gives wonderful pictures and links for you to examine.